# remeshing a vtk file with mmg (mmgs) file using a size map

Tags: mesh, vtk

I’m using [mmgtools's](http://www.mmgtools.org) mmgs to remesh some polydata (vtp files). I need to control the cell size according to a metric, so I provide a size map. However, I can’t succeed to make mmgs take this size map into account. For now, I'm trying with just a constant size.

If I provide a constant size at the command line (`mmgs_O3 test.vtp -hsiz .001`), it works as expected.

However if I save this same size in point data, suffixed with :metric (as explained in the [prerequisite section](https://www.mmgtools.org/mmg-remesher-try-mmg/mmg-remesher-tutorials#prereq)):

```
> mesh.point_data["size:metric"]
pyvista_ndarray([0.001, 0.001, 0.001, ..., 0.001, 0.001, 0.001])
```

Then mmgs (`mmgs_O3 test.vtp`) just remeshes ignoring the size map.

I note however that mmgs does read this field as if I create another one suffixed with :metric, it fails with an error `## Error:MMG5_count_vtkEntities: 2 metric fields detected (labelled with a string containing the 'metric' keyword).`.

So, I must be missing something, but can’t find what. Does anyone have experience with this tool? What do I miss for mmgs to take this size into account?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself, it's because the mesh contained other data values. In that case mmgs doesn't fail, but remeshes while ignoring the passed size metric.

In order to work, the mesh's cells and point must be stripped of any other data, and contain only the `:metric` value.